# error when adding a new xib in main interface

Tags: ios, xcode, view

downloaded here [this parser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) launched, it works, but when I want to change main interface (the default setting is MainWindow.xib, and I want to put my xib), shows the following error. I wish that I was a structure MyNewXib.xib - MainWindow.xib - RootViewController.xib,  but when I add in MainInterface MyNewXib.xib get this error, how do I fix it.

```
    2015-03-23 11:27:02.686 TetraVer 1.1[411:5899] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7fa352c30c10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e1ba75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fad9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e1b6b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f42fd43 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d655e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e3f54ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010e3f6f92 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 160
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010e12dc71 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 46
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e12cd2b -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1074
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010e12bd35 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010fe84243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d50c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d469c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d46785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110d45bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010e12b7a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e12e580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  TetraVer 1.1                        0x000000010e06c6f4 main + 68
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114c7d145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the elements linked correctly with interface and definition (check the outlet for you xib elements). This error comes usually when you have one ore more element in xib witch definition (@property) was deleted.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to transfer the @property xib (which by default is in the mainIntaface) in the one xib that I created?

Comment: As I said, check your elements in xib, see if there are defined in your .h file and double check your .m implementation. If you have for example an UILabel named MyLabel linked (that has an outlet in a second xib), and you change your xib file  owner, you will got exceptions, because the element lost it's connection.

Comment: ... You understand me correctly, I do not want to swap the new and old .Xib, I mean that I want to create a new .Xib and make it the button "news" and this button will lead to the MainWindow.xib? I think I need to change something in mayn.m but i don't understand where i can do this


 - my main.m

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
        return retVal;
    }
}